# Sql : cвязь полей одной таблицы со значениями второй

Tags: sql, er-diagram

У меня вопрос по проектированию схемы. Занимаюсь задачей "аэропорт". Есть сущность "рейс" и необходимо внести туда данные "место отправления" и "место прибытия" из таблицы "аэропорты"(страна , город аэропорта).
Как это правильно отобразить на схеме? Я ведь оперирую одной таблицей для заполнения этих полей.

Спасибо!

Comment: *Я ведь оперирую одной таблицей для заполнения этих полей.* Нет. Вы оперируете двумя независимыми копиями этой таблицы. Вот на схеме эти две копии и рисуйте.

Comment: Вы могли бы скинуть пример реализации, пожалуйста? Впервые сталкиваюсь с таким вопросом .

Comment: *Вы могли бы скинуть пример реализации* На SO.ru нет возможности прикладывать файлы.

Comment: Впрочем, сделайте самостоятельно. На новую диаграмму поместите 2 таблицы "аэропорты" и одну таблицу "рейсы". В свойствах укажите таблицам "аэропорты" имена/алиасы/псевдонимы (смотря какой инструмент пользуете) "аэропорты_1" и "аэропорты_2". Свяжите поле "место отправления" таблицы "рейсы" с ИД таблицы "аэропорты_1". Свяжите поле "место прибытия" таблицы "рейсы" с ИД таблицы "аэропорты_2".  Всё, собсно...